# Html.LabelFor with Type and a property name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there way to write something like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(typeof(StackViewModel), "SomeProperty")
```

I'm generating a table (but can't use @Html.TableFor) and want to use @Html.LabelFor to generate the table column titles, but since the table may or may not have any rows, I don't have an object to work with, just the type of that object.

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm looking to use the typeof() because my situation is like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(Model.TableRows.First().Id)
```

And if "TableRows" has no rows, `.First()` throws.

Comment: why not use `FirstOrDefault()`? and new operators like `.?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a non-generic `Html` helper and pass a `Type` and property name, as an option you can create such extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor(this HtmlHelper html, 
                                           Type modelType, string expression)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current
                      .GetMetadataForProperty(null, modelType, expression);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(metadata.GetDisplayName());
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(typeof(Sample.Models.Category), "Id")
```

**Note:**

- You can enhance the method and add some validation rules and exception handling if you need.
- For cases that your model is of type `IEnumerable<T>` and you can use a lambda expression for your property like `x=>x.Id` you can use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.Id)`. It also works if the `Model` is null or has no rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(Model != null)
{
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th> 
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
}
```

Or you can replace `@Html.DisplayNameFor` to `@Html.LabelFor`.

Why not?

Comment: Because "@Html.DisplayNameFor(Model.TableRows.First().Id)" would crash if there were no rows.

Comment: Why you are not checking for row existence before using it?

Comment: Because the table's header must have labels even if the table has no rows. If the table has no rows, I can't just not display anything at all.

Comment: For cases that you want to use a generic helper which its model is of type `IEnumerable<T>` and you can use a lambda expression for your property the answer of @SeM is correct and you just need to put the if statement around the part that renders rows based on your requirement. It also works if the `Model` is null or has no rows. But when you want to  use property name or when you want to use a non-generic helper, you should create your helper method as I did in the answer. +1

Comment: Model is *not* a collection nor enumerable in this case; once again the path is `Model.TableRows`.